# Byte array to string in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, string, byte

I've done some research on changing bytes to strings but I am not sure where I have to begin with the specific file I have.

I have a file called Options.mco and when I open it in notepad++ or notepad it's all just gibberish.

http://puu.sh/3lHJD.png

http://puu.sh/3lHKm.png

So I want to turn these bytes into strings so that I can then edit them in my program depending on what option the user chooses and then change them back into byte form and save it in the file keeping the same file structure.

From my research I found out how to convert bytes into string and string into bytes but I am not sure where to start with this because of it's layout and how I should import or view it after the bytes have been converted.

Comment: You need to find out how an .mco file is structured. This page: http://mco.file-extension-library.com/ suggests that it is actually a zip archive with a different filename extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sussing out the format of the file? How do I do this?

A hex editor will help.  Knowing the software that generated the file will help to identify what type of information is in the file.

Comment: I know what information is contained in the file. Information such as aspect ratio for the program. I have looked at it with HxD and I wasn't able to understand but I know that if a setting is changed in the program the values change.

Comment: Then you should be able to use that.  Change an option in the program and see what values change in the file.  Repeat this through all the options and log what bytes are changing and what option changed them.  You should be able to see some sort of pattern emerge.  Typically a start byte and/or an end byte to signify a block of data.

Comment: And then do what with those values? change them depending on what option is selected and then write them in and save it?

Comment: Once you have an outline of the byte structure, now you know how to tell what is a data block and also what bytes  you need to change to affect different options.

Comment: Okay I understand it better now. I will try researching a few things tomorrow and I will see what I can achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You **need** to know the layout of that `Options.mco` file.  It sounds like a binary file written to disk from memory, which means that you have all of the issues with reading a flat text file, plus character encoding, plus not having any good way to tell the difference between "this bit is part of a string" and "that bit is a boolean value."

If you have any control at all over the generation of the file, consider switching to XML or JSON (or, heck, INI or just plain text) to store the options.

Otherwise, you will need to determine exactly how the `Options.mco` file is laid out internally, parse out the strings viable to change, change the strings, put them back, convert your strings back to binary, write back to the file... and hope that you didn't flip a bit somewhere that makes the entire thing corrupt.

Comment: Aww man this is harder than I expected. I don't have control over the generation of the file either.

Comment: Well, if it's something you have to do, you'll still need to start with sussing out the format of the file.  (And we're assuming all along that it's not encrypted with a private key internal to some other program...)

Comment: Sussing out the format of the file? How do I do this? As far as I am aware it's not encrypted. Someone told me I need to do this: "You need to convert your ratios into hex and be sure it's applied into that (width - 4bytes and height - 4bytes)."

Comment: There's context that seems to be missing here.  If this is for a school project, ask for help.  If this is a professional project, meet with the other team and establish a good exchange protocol. And if this is for a personal project... well, good luck.